# run react-native detox e2e tests on real devices

Tags: react-native, aws-device-farm, detox

Is there a way to run detox e2e tests on real devices within a CI pipeline?

My goal is to run the tests on AWS device farm or something similar.

I read that it is possible to run the e2e tests on bitrise ci, but I guess they will be executed in the iOS simulator, right?

Any hint appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question appsthatmatter. We are planning to support the Detox test framework and CI integration in the future. This is currently in the backlog.

Comment: I would also love to see some documentation about running detox e2e tests on android using firebase test lab. Is this possible as of now? Does detox support this? I am doing detox android e2e on circleci, with 2 . problems - 1. circle ci (2) still does not support x86 bases emulators, so I am using ARM based ems and 2. Its really slow, detox hits a timeout before even the emulator starts / app gets installed, so firebase test lab comes into picture - does detox support this?

Comment: Any update on this topic by any chance? I am able to run it on a locally usb connected device, but cannot run it on a remotely connected device.

I have outlined what I have done on this github issue: https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/1616

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported, but it is on the roadmap to allow support for real devices. I would guess there is little chance to have a device farm solution, because this would require action from amazon, as far as I know.

Comment: why would that require action from Amazon?

Comment: To run it on AWS device farm